# Azure pipelines timing out when I add a variable group using msft-hosted agent deploying terraform code

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

My Azure pipeline is timing out on terraform plan/apply when I add variable groups.

The variables

[image]

Variable group

[image]

I tried to do some research but to no avail.

yml

[image]

Comment: Posting logs from the failing pipeline would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running Terraform in a pipeline you need to pass the parameter `-input-false`. This will cause Terraform to immediately output the error and I suspect it's saying something like `the input variable vnet_name is not set` because you have not explained how you are joining the variable group to Terraform. It is not enough to simply add the pipeline variables, you must also pass them into Terraform.

There are a number of ways of passing values into Terraform as described in this page here: https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#assigning-values-to-root-module-variables

The most common method I have seen used is to create an `environment.tfvars` file. This is a simple key:pair value of variables which you can hard-code variables into which you then pass into Terraform like `terraform apply -var-file="environment.tfvars"`

If you have values in Azure Pipelines that you want to place there, you can use the Azure Replace Tokens tasks. (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

In which case your `environment.tfvars` will look like this:

```
vnet_name = #{vnet_name}#
```

The Replace Token Task will replace the Azure Pipeline variable `vnet_name` with the value described in your variable group.

Comment: Does that mean we can't just reference the variable groups like we do when using ARM templates ?

Comment: No. Terraform is not automatically aware of Azure Pipeline variable groups. You must plumb them in using one of the methods described in my post or the documentation linked.

Comment: Thanks a lot James, will give that a try

Comment: Thanks if this answer helped you please remember to mark it as answered. Feel free to ask for clarification again if you get stuck :)